# How do I use a parameter for my tablename in my sql procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I don't get any errors when I do this, but it creates a table called "dbo.@tablename" in my database when i really want is for it to create the value that i am passing as the parameter in the exec procedure as the tablename. What am i doing wrong. Here is my update procedure script. Maybe i can change so so that it does create the value as the table name.

Here is what i have so far:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Load_Negatives]
        -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
        @TABLENAME SYSNAME, 
        @AuditPeriodStartDate datetime,
        @AuditPeriodEndDate datetime
    AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
Select 
    Location,
    Customer,
    Transaction_date
    into
        dbo.[@TABLENAME]
     from dbo.CustomerHistory (nolock)
    where
    [Transaction_date] between @AuditPeriodStartDate and @AuditPeriodEndDate

END
```

Comment: Use dynamic SQL. Put your select statement into an Nvarchar using `...[' + @TABLENAME + ']...` for the table part of it and then `Exec sp_executeSQL` it.

Answer (score 7):

Table names cannot be parametrised. Therefore, you need to build your SQL statement dynamically, incorporating the name into the dynamic script.

To minimise the risk of SQL injection, use the [`QUOTENAME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) system function with the `@TABLENAME` value and introduce parametrisation to your dynamic query to pass the other two parameters of the stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Load_Negatives]
    @TABLENAME SYSNAME, 
    @AuditPeriodStartDate datetime,
    @AuditPeriodEndDate datetime
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);
SET @sql = N'Select 
    Location,
    Customer,
    Transaction_date
    into
        dbo.' + QUOTENAME(@TABLENAME) + N'
     from dbo.CustomerHistory (nolock)
    where
    [Transaction_date] between @AuditPeriodStartDate and @AuditPeriodEndDate'
;
EXECUTE sp_executesql
    @sql,
    N'@AuditPeriodStartDate datetime, @AuditPeriodEndDate datetime',
    @AuditPeriodStartDate, @AuditPeriodEndDate
;

END
```

Basically, the dynamic query looks almost exactly the same as your current query. The only difference is that the table name is added as the result of `QUOTENAME(@TABLENAME)`. The `datetime` parameters of the dynamic query happen to have same names as the corresponding parameters of the stored procedure but that is not mandatory.

The `EXECUTE sp_executesql` statement passes the `datetime` arguments to the dynamic query and then executes it.

One other note is about your use of the `BETWEEN` predicate with `datetime` values. If `Transaction_date` includes timestamps with non-zero time portions, it would be much better to specify the range in this form:

```
 [Transaction_date] >= @AuditPeriodStartDate
 and
 [Transaction_date] < @AuditPeriodEndDate
```

That way you can be sure the results will include only relevant values. More information can be found in this blog article:

- [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Comment: I have been told by some SQL Experts that using between for dates is not a good idea, it outputs different results in different environments.

Comment: cheers pal and could you please look at my answer for this question and suggest if it can be improved in any way . I think my solution is still vulnerable to injection attack any advice please.  cheers :)

Comment: I can't see that it's vulnerable to SQL injection any more than my suggestion. You aren't using parametrisation of the datetime arguments, but that doesn't open the query to SQL injection attacks. In my opinion, though, it would still be cleaner to use parametrisation. (Although if you do add it, your answer will become a duplicate of mine in that respect.) Also, you haven't really resolved the BETWEEN issue, because you've merely replaced it with an *exact equivalent*. Please read the article linked in my answer for an explanation of what is wrong with BETWEEN when it's used with datetimes.

Comment: Thank you for feedback much appreciated I will definitely have a look at this article. Cheers pal